# File download with Jquery Mobile and ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-mobile

I have a page in my website that requires a simple file download link. This link is implemented via the combination of an `action link` and a `File` `ActionResult` like so:

View Code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = 1 }, new { @data_role = "button" })
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Download(int? id)
{
  ..
  ..
  return File(fileStream, fileInfo.Extension, fileInfo.Name);
}
```

This works fine without Jquery Mobile applied, but when I switch on Jquery mobile the page freezes up after the action method returns from my controller.

Do I need to do something special with Jquery mobile for this to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to turn off the ajax loading for that link. There are a couple of ways to do it, adding rel="external" being one of them.